# Android AdapterView addition animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have a Fragment which consists of a single GridView. The user can click an action bar icon to add a new item to the bottom of this GridView. I would like to have this action represented by an animation where the GridView scrolls to the bottom of the pre-addition dataset, then scrolls one row down (if necessary to fit the new item), and then animates the addition of the new item.

My GridView is backed by a CursorAdapter, which is populated by a ContentProvider using a Loader, so dataset updates are provided by swapping out the Cursor in `onLoadFinished()`.

I've broken down the procedure into several steps:

1. If not already there, scroll to the bottom of the existing dataset
2. Detect the end of the scrolling event
3. At the end of the scrolling event, add the item to the backing data set, triggering layout
4. On the next PreDraw event (provided by a `ViewTreeObserver`, animate the old views up one row if necessary
5. Animate the new item into the grid

Of those, 2 and 4 are tricky. At least for 2, a relatively easy inelegant solution exists - I call `GridView.smoothScrollToPosition(GridView.getCount())`, then `Handler.postDelayed(RestOfAnimationRunnable, SOME_INTERVAL)` pending upon `GridView.getLastVisiblePosition()` being equal to `GridView.getCount() - 1`. It's ugly, but it works. (If you have a better idea, please let me know!)

The problem with 4 is that the pattern of performing animations using a `ViewTreeObserver` to perform animations depends on getting the correct final condition from Android, as described in many resources about [Android animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wyhY68esZY). In other words, the new view must be the last visible view, but if the GridView's last row is full, it will be the first view in a new offscreen row.

So what I am looking for is some way of telling the GridView to scroll all the way to the bottom, and to do so between steps 3 and 4, and to do so without drawing this to the screen (as it would screw up the animation). So far I've tried:

- **Setting the GridView to transcript mode**: This works, but causes other glitches (For example, if the last row has room for a new item, the existing items will become fully transparent) and even negatively affects other animations I have on this GridView.
- **Setting the GridView's selection to the newly-created last item**: This is probably what I'm looking for, but I am not sure where to put it. I've tried having it right after the `swapCursor()` that causes the GridView to refresh, but this doesn't seem to have any effect. Perhaps an additional step is required, like manually requesting layout.

I think I'm on the right track with the second of the above solutions, but I'd like to get some advice from someone who knows more than me about this, because it's getting pretty hacky and I feel like I could mess things up pretty badly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel I understand enough of where you already are with the code to give a great answer. This could be an approach.

1. Add a new item to the list but have it be empty so some fields are default or null.
2. Detect these default/null fields and have the CursorAdapter render the view as transparent and/or with 0 or 1px height.
3. Then scroll the list to that element in the list.
4. At the point that the view is "visible", add the real data.
5. Then trigger the addition animation.

Comment: This is a much better solution than what I had in mind. Thanks!